# I want to rel=nofollow wordpress images

Tags: images, templates, page-template

I have a default theme. When i add media to wordpress site. By default it use simple "a href" tag I want to add attribute "rel=nofollow" to it. Can anybody please point me in right direction?.

Comment: You have tagged this question with both [tag:wordpress.com] and [tag:wordpress.org] - is this a question about a self-hosted WP (and hence on-topic) or about a blog on wordpress.com (and hence not)?

Comment: Not a blog. Self hosted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook into the [image_send_to_editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_send_to_editor/) filter.  This allows you to modify the markup used when inserting an image into the content editor.

Something like this should work:

```
add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'my_add_rel_nofollow', 10, 8);
function my_add_rel_nofollow($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ){

    // check if there is already a rel value
    if ( preg_match('/<a.*? rel=".*?">/', $html) ) {
        $html = preg_replace('/(<a.*? rel=".*?)(".*?>)/', '$1 ' . 'nofollow' . '$2', $html);
    } else {
        $html = preg_replace('/(<a.*?)>/', '$1 rel="' . 'nofollow' . '" >', $html);
    }
    return $html;
}
```

This will first check if there is already a `rel` attribute, and add the no_follow.  Or, if there is no `rel` attribute, it will add one, and set it to `nofollow`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  Not sure if its always been there pf if its part a nofollow plugin?[image]

Comment: This is indeed core functionality.